# MyPOS Payment Gateway integration with PHP Laravel via API (Not SDK)

Tags: php, laravel, payment, document

I am trying to implement myPOS (https://www.mypos.eu/) with PHP with API and flutter.
Basically I want to strike API call by the Laravel from flutter app to MYPOS gateway.

I have gone through the official documents with [this link](https://github.com/developermypos/myPOS-Checkout-SDK-PHP). The OAuth API as per this [link](https://developers.mypos.eu/en/doc/more_apis/v1_0) implemented with PHP but not able to get the results.
I have created the developer account, added the client_id, client_secrets at the required place, followed all the given steps in official document, but still not able to get the required and expected results.

It seems, at some point, the official document is missing some steps with example for the implementation.

It would be great if one can provide an example.